# Grab URL using PHP

Tags: php

I have a script that grabs the current page url & stores it in a variable:

`$page = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

I then check this URL for a phrase to check what page the user is on.

`if (strpos($page,'celtic') !== false) { echo 'this is the celtic page'; }`

However, I have found a bug in this.

If the domain contains the phrase `celtic`, it won't work.

How can I test just the 3rd part of the URL so it would return true if the domain was `www.celticfootball.com/teams/scotland/celtic/`.

Comment: Does it not work in some special way?

Comment: ... just test `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try do smth like this:
$params = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    switch(true) {
      case (bool) strpos($params, 'celtic'):
        echo 'celtic';
        break;
      case (bool) strpos($params, 'another'):
        echo 'another';
        break;
      default:
        //ignore
      break;
    }
```